# How to create android 12 pill shape app bar in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I was wandering if its a way in flutter to include an app bar like the one in android 12 Google apps (like: Play store, messages, phone etc).

[image: A screenshot of what I want to implement]

Comment: You can do it using Container decoration with Row inside. Can you include what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a combination of widgets with some decorations

wireframe would be

- Container with decorations

  - Row

    - Expanded Textfield with suffix and prefix
    - SizedBox with some width
    - Icon button

Create a widget following those and should be able to create that

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy you just need to put TextFormField/TextField inside a container
like

```
                                    Container(
                                                 ....
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                borderRadius:
                                                     BorderRadius.circular(
                                                          15), 
                                                child:  TextFormField(
                                                        decoration:InputDecoration(prefixIcon: 'YOUR PREFIX ICON WIDGET', prefixIcon: 'YOUR SUFFIX ICON WIDGET MAY BE A ROW WIDGET'
                                                   
                                                    ))
                                                  ....
```

to change look and feel use container more decoration properties like color and others.